# binding & pmap interaction change?

Tags: binding, clojure, thread-local, dynamic-variables, pmap

There are several somewhat old blog posts out there advising caution when mixing dynamic variables, `binding`, and `pmap`, e.g. [here](http://cemerick.com/2009/11/03/be-mindful-of-clojures-binding/), where we get the following code snippet:

```
user=> (def *foo* 5)
#'user/*foo*
user=> (defn adder
             [param]
             (+ *foo* param))
#'user/adder
user=> (binding [*foo* 10]
         (doseq [v (pmap adder (repeat 3 5))]
           (println v)))
10
10
10
nil
```

But that's not what happens when I run that code (changing the first line to `(def ^:dynamic *foo* 5)`). I get three `15`s as output (using Clojure 1.4), just as you would naïvely expect—that is, with the change in the binding form seen by the function passed to pmap. Have the way thread-local bindings and pmap interact changed? I can't find this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting in 1.3 the set of local bindings are sent to pmap along with the function. So as long as you mark the var ^:dynamic this is no longer a problem. This feature it called **Binding Conveyance** and is included in the 1.3 changelog:

from: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.3.x/changes.txt

```
Clojure APIs that pass work off to other threads (e.g. send, send-off, pmap, future) now convey the dynamic bindings of the calling thread:

  (def ^:dynamic *num* 1)
  (binding [*num* 2] (future (println *num*)))
  ;; prints "2", not "1"
```

Comment: thanks! where is this documented? it's not in http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/1.3